# Magic hourglass of squares hyperelliptic equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

I have been looking into the problem of the magic square of squares, or more specifically, the magic hourglass of squares, like so:

$a^2$  $b^2$   $c^2$

$ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $  $d^2$

$e^2$ $f^2$ $g^2$

Where both rows, the column, and the two diagonals add to the same total. It turns out, when you pick values of a, d, g which satisfy this, and try to find ways to make three of the four other terms work, you end up with an elliptic curve, which has rank 2. This can be parametrized, and taking one of the generators, you end up with:

$a=(m^2-2mn-n^2)(m^2+n^2)(5m^2-4mn+n^2)$,

$b=(m^2+2mn-n^2)(7m^4-16m^3n+6m^2n^2-n^4)$,

$c=m^6+24m^5n-13m^4n^2-16m^3n^3+19m^2n^4-8mn^5+n^6$

$d=(m^2+n^2)^2(5m^2-4mn+n^2)$

$f=m^6-26m^5n+17m^4n^2+12m^3n^3-17m^2n^4+6mn^5-n^6$

$g=(m^2+2mn-n^2)(m^2+n^2)(5m^2-4mn+n^2)$

In order for this to be a true hourglass of squares, the $e^2$ term must also work, yielding the equation:

$e^2=49m^{12}-128m^{11}n-298m^{10}n^2+320m^9n^3+1071m^8n^4-1856m^7n^5+1140m^6n^6-64m^5n^7-321m^4n^8+192m^3n^9-42m^2n^{10}+n^{12}$

Or, after switching variables and dehomogenizing:

$y^2=49x^{12}-128x^{11}-298x^{10}+320x^9+1071x^8-1856x^7+1140x^6-64x^5-321x^4+192x^3-42x^2+1$

Solving this equation is quite a bit above my paygrade as an amateur mathematician.

Are there any rational solutions to this equation, other than the trivial $x=0, 1, -1$, or the point at infinity? Any new solution would immediately yield a solution to the previously unsolved magic hourglass of squares!

Comment: First thought: have you tried working modulo small numbers? Mod 3, 8 and 5 all come to mind as being worth a quick try to prove impossibility from. (Though this will admittedly only give integer solutions, not rational.)

Comment: The existence of a few trivial integer solutions seems to rule out the modular approach, especially for small bases such as 3, 5, or 8.

Comment: Every m,n combination in mod 3, mod 5, and mod 8 works to make e^2 a square, so that is out.

Comment: It's not clear to me from the presentation, where what's already known stops, and what's your new work, if any, begins. If the $y^2=49x^{12}+\cdots$ equation is already in the literature, and no nontrivial solutions are known, that suggests that so far the problem is above everyone's pay grade, not just yours.

Comment: The hyperelliptic curve $y^{2} = 49x^{12} + \cdots$ has genus $5$ and it has an automorphism group of order $4$. One quotient of this is the genus $3$ curve $X : y^{2} = (x^{2}-2)(x^{6} - 6x^{5} + 3x^{4} + 16x^{3} - 9x^{2} - 10x + 1)$. An upper bound for the rank of $J(X)$ is $2$. If someone could find two independent points of infinite order on $J(X)$, Chabauty's method could be used to provably find all the rational points on $X$ and hence on the original curve.

Comment: The formulation of the problem is not quite clear to me. Maybe it should be formulated in a formal way? If one approach to solving it does not give a result, maybe it's worth going back to the beginning and solving it in another way? Formulate it formally.

Comment: Bremner considered the problem of magic square of squares (see [link](https://www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/acta-arithmetica/all/99/3/82367/on-squares-of-squares-ii) and [link](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa88/aa8837.pdf)). It is mentioned that Duncan Buell handled the "hour-glass" configuration, however I only found this preprint: [link](http://www.multimagie.com/Buell.pdf).

Comment: In Bremner's Squares of squares II article you may find solutions of the "hour-glass" configuration over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}).$

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ one has for example $$\begin{matrix}(7+\sqrt{3})^2 & (7-\sqrt{3})^2 & 14^2\\ & 10^2 &\\ 2^2 & (1+7\sqrt{3})^2 & (-1+7\sqrt{3})^2\end{matrix}$$ provided by Michaud-Rodgers [link](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/michaud/fourthyearproject.pdf).

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, I followed my own ideas and reasoning. I didn't get any of the ideas from a paper so as far as I know, this is a unique method, although others could have done it. If you want I can write out in an extension to my question a more fleshed out working. Potentially that would allow for more of the other possible curves to be checked as well.

Comment: I'd be worried, Thomas, that you might be reinventing the wheel. As noted in other comments, Andrew Bremner and others have studied this problem before. You might get some ideas from their work, or you might find they've already been where you are.

Comment: Looking at the papers, it seems that Bremner has been where I am. However, they haven't resolved many of the hyperelliptic curves. They did find some curves of degree 8, which might be easier to analyze...

Comment: "This can be parametrized, and taking one of the generators, you end up with:" Are there other generators that you could've used instead to generate other equations than just "$49 m^{12} - ... + 1$" ?

Comment: The elliptic fibration has rank 2, so there are a potentially infinite number of choices I could have made.